# Relative minus sign in $\gamma\gamma\to e^+e^-$ scattering

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I need to compute the scattering amplitude for the process $\gamma\gamma\to e^+e^-$ at tree-level in QED. In my notes, it is written that there are two Feynman diagrams for this process, but I only seem to find one. My reasoning is the following:

1. The incoming photons are distinguishable (as I think all incoming particles are), since I can know their momenta, so no need to account for swapping them with a different diagram.
2. The outgoing fermions are different particles, thus distinguishable.

I would conclude that there is just the t-channel diagram at tree-level, but this is wrong. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incomming *particles* may be identical, but they may have diferent *momenta* $p_1$ and $p_2$ If you draw the t-channel diagram with the $e^+$ leaving  at the top right and the $e^-$ leaving at the bottom  right, there is one diagram with momentum $p_1$ incoming at the top left and $p_2$ incoming at the bottom, and one diagram with the momenta interchanged.